# How to parse variables to JSON Object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I want to be able to parse external variables into a JSON object.

Something like this would do:

```
var username = "zvincze";
```

And using that variable to parse a JSON object:

```
var json = '{"username":"VARIABLE_GOES_HERE"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

This is a very simple question that I can't seem to figure out.  In fact, I don't even know if there's a way to actually acheive something such as this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish carefully between JSON and JavaScript objects. They are two entirely different things.

JSON is a **language-independent character-based data representation** that is used for data interchange. For instance, if you are sending data to a server, it needs to be in string form, so you would need to convert your data into JSON. If you are receiving data from a server, and it is JSON format, you need to convert it into a JavaScript object so you can use it in your JavaScript program.

JSON actually has nothing to do with JavaScript. For example, JSON could be used as a string-based data representation for Java programs exchanging data. Java and pretty much all other languages provide their own library routines for converting their native data into JSON and vice versa.

The only relationship between JSON and JavaScript objects used in JavaScript is that a JSON string **looks** much like a JavaScript object literal, with some additional restrictions, such as that keys must be quoted, that it cannot hold certain data types such as functions, and that it cannot hold circular references.

The "JS" part of "JSON" does not indicate that JSON is a basic JavaScript data structure, or that JSON is used in JavaScript for representing or manipulating data. It merely comes from the fact that, as mentioned above, the format of a JSON string is loosely modeled after that of a JavaScript object literal.

In normal day-to-day JavaScript programming, you will never use JSON, and don't need to worry about it. You will need to worry about JSON **only** when, as I said, you are sending data to somewhere, or receiving data from somewhere, that expects JSON as the data format. That is the case when making ajax calls, of course, but actually, even then, since jQuery's `$.ajax` will automatically convert data to and from JavaScript objects if you tell it the right types, even in that case you do not normally need to worry about JSON.

Note by the way that JSON can represent primitive values, not just JavaScript objects. For example, `"1"` is valid JSON which represents the number 1.

As I understand your question, you want to create a JavaScript object (not JSON) which contains as one of its values that of the variable `username`. You create a JavaScript object with regular old JavaScript object literal format, in this case

```
{username: username}
```

This means, create an object, with a single key named `"username"` (quote it if you please), whose value is that of the variable `username`. Again, unless you plan to send this object somewhere that expects a JSON string representation, there is no need to even think about JSON in this case.

In theory, yes, as one answer suggested, you could create a JSON string with the value of `username` "interpolated", using string arithmetic like `'{"username":"' + VARIABLE_GOES_HERE + '"}'`, and then convert that JSON string into a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse`. However, there is absolutely no reason to jump through these hoops, when you can simply write the JavaScript object as a normal JavaScript object literal.

Another answer shows a way to define a regular JavaScript object, and then turn it into JSON using `JSON.stringify`. However, again, in your case, there is no need to do this unless you are planning to send the object somewhere.

Yet another answer shows a way to define a regular JavaScript object, then stringify it into a JSON string, then immediately parse it back into a JavaScript object, which will be exactly the same object you started with before stringifying and parsing. There's absolutely no need to do this.

One sees no small number of questions on SO trying to somehow manipulate or search or replace within JSON, using regexps for example. There are almost no cases where you need to even think of doing such a thing. JSON has two fundamental operations: converting values into JSON, and converting JSON into values. Both of those are built into the language in the form of `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, that do their jobs with absolute reliability and performance. If for some reason you need to modify data which is in JSON string format, don't manipulate the string; all you need to do is parse it into a JavaScript value, manipulate the value, and then convert it back into JSON.

Unfortunately, for unknown reasons, many JavaScript programmers who are learning the language, including many who have posted questions here on SO, have developed the misperception that JSON **is** a JavaScript object, or that they must think about JSON and stringifying and parsing in order to deal with plain old JavaScript objects, which is very much **not** the case.

Minor point, but you use the term "parse" in your question. I see more and more people using this word for some reason to mean "access" or "retrieve" or "extract". Actually, "parse" has a very specific meaning: to analyze a string-based representation of information (such as a program or data object), according to a particular grammar, into some suitable computer-friendly form for further processing. What `JSON.parse` does **is** parsing in this sense, because it is analyzing a string-based representation of information according to the JSON grammar into a JavaScript object for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Without messing with concatenation `var json = '{"username":"'+ userName +'"}'` you can:

```
var ob = {};              // or simply: var ob = {username:"zvincze"};
ob.surname = "Zvincze";
ob.name    = "Zachary";
ob.id      = "5182842";

var json = JSON.stringify(ob);
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate strings like below...

```
var json = '{"username":"' + VARIABLE_GOES_HERE + '"}'
```

in your case:

```
var username = "zvincze";  
var json = '{"username":"' + username + '"}';
```

Happy coding....

Comment: Can someone please explain me why down voted my answer. And please next time leave an explanation when you do it. Is it because question is down voted ?. I didn't know there's such a rule like that in SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing is sort of odd.  The object you create is json by definition (JavaScript Object Notation).

```
var obj = {};
obj.username = "zvincze";

//obj is now json
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
//str == {'username':'zvincze'}
```

`JSON.parse(obj)` should fail since `obj` is already json.

Comment: The OP does not want to create JSON in the sense of a character-based data representation (string); he apparently just wants to create a JS object, which he can do by nothing more complicated than `{username: username}`.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "obj is now json". It is not JSON; it is a plain old JavaScript object, which could be stringified into a JSON string if desired (but that doesn't seem to be what the OP intends).

Comment: So then why does `JSON.stringfy(obj)` work if the `obj` is not JSON (as you say)?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` does not operate on JSON. It operates on regular JavaScript objects, and **turns them into** JSON.

Comment: So you're saying `typeof JSON === 'string'` basically?

Comment: JSON is a string. From json.org: *JSON is a text format.*

Answer (score -1):

`var json = JSON.stringify({username:"zvincze"})`