# Accessing json generated by stringify

Tags: arrays, json, express, ejs, stringify

I have an array in which data from db is stored. I have converted this array into JSON by stringify which results in json like this:

```
var view_data = [{ f o o = " boo " , t e x t = "t e s t " }];
```

When i try to access this foo object  via for loop like this :

```
 for(var d=0; d<view_data.length; d++)
 {
   print view_data[d].foo;
 }
```

It gives undefined. I think this is not actually json object is array of strings.
Please help me to access the key-value pair.

Comment: the output of stringify is a string, not an object

Comment: how should then access the array as json object

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be fuzzy on the meaning of JSON. JSON is a string-based format used for exchanging data. It's not used, and is irrelevant, in the course of normal programming in JavaScript, unless you're sending data to somewhere, or receiving data from somewhere, in JSON format.

> I have converted this array into JSON by stringify which results in json like this:

```
var view_data = [{ f o o = " boo " , t e x t = "t e s t " }];
```

`JSON.stringify` takes a JavaScript object and converts it into a string-based format. Therefore this is impossible. `JSON.stringify` would always return a string, not a (broken) JS object as you have shown.

In your sample data, you have shown extra spaces in the property names: `"f o o"` instead of `"foo"`. If in fact that's how you have attempted to specify your JS object, it won't work at all. It's invalid syntax. It is also invalid syntax to use an equal sign; you need a colon.

If you define your JS object correctly, then the code you showed will work fine:

```
var view_data = [{foo: "boo" , text: "test"}];

for (var d=0; d<view_data.length; d++) {
  print view_data[d].foo;
}
```

> Accessing json generated by stringify

You don't access JSON generated by stringify. JSON is a string format meant only use in communicating with some external system.

> how should then access the array as json object

There is no such thing as a JSON object. There is JSON, which is a string; and there are JavaScript objects.

For more information on JavaScript objects vs. JSON, see [How to parse variables to JSON Object (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446613/how-to-parse-variables-to-json-object-javascript/34451031#34451031).

Comment: Actually i'm new to Js. So,please help. What i have an app in express in which there is an array in which i have collected data from the postgresql query. I want it to send to another ejs template. The parse function is not working so i used stringify.

Comment: Please tag the question as node, express, and/or ejs. Provide code.